# Duda en SQL compleja de agrupación

Tags: sql

Buenas tardes,
Dispongo de la siguiente tabla, en la que muestro tickets de compra, en cada color distinto he agrupado los artículos de un mismo ticket. No hay un identificador de ticket como tal, pero internamente se puede usar como identificador la fecha+el cliente:

[image: Tickets]

La clave primaria sería fecha+cliente+articulo.

Mi duda es:

**¿Cómo podría sacar, para cada artículo, la suma de veces que se han comprado otros en el mismo ticket?**

En el ejemplo, para "caramelos fresa", obtendríamos un 2 para caramelos plátano (uno del amarillo y otro del morado) y otro 2 para caramelos de coco (uno del amarillo y otro del rosa).

Los pasos lógicos serían, para un artículo de prueba "caramelos fresa":

1. Saco los tickets en los que se han comprado al menos un caramelo fresa.
2. De ellos, hago un distinct del resto de artículos
3. Obtengo el count de artículos diferentes comprados conjuntamente con el caramelo fresa.
4. Extiendo esto para la totalidad de artículos.

¿Alguien podría echarme una mano?
Gracias!

Comment: qué motor de base de datos estás usando?

Comment: Estoy usando mysql, a través de phpmyadmin o workbench indistintamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener los tickets que tienen algún "caramelos fresa":

```
select distinct fecha_ticket_id, cliente_id
from tickets
where articulo_id = 1
```

Esa consulta, la podemos usar para filtrar solo los tickets que tienen algún "caramelos fresa":

```
select *
from tickets A
where exists (select *
              from tickets B
              where articulo_id = 1
                and A.fecha_ticket_id = B.fecha_ticket_id
                and A.cliente_id = B.cliente_id)
```

Ahora lo único que resta es excluir los "caramelos fresa", y agrupar por artículo:

```
select A.articulo_id, A.articulo_desc, count(*)
from tickets A
where exists (select *
              from tickets B
              where B.articulo_id = 1
                and A.fecha_ticket_id = B.fecha_ticket_id
                and A.cliente_id = B.cliente_id)
  and A.articulo_id <> 1
group by A.articulo_id, A.articulo_desc
```

Comment: Genial! muchísimas gracias!